# Ffmpeg map and filter_complex subprocess - Python

Tags: python, shell, ffmpeg

I want to crop and re encode videos via ffmpeg from within python using subprocesses.

I managed starting a subprocess using a pure string command and shell=True but I want to build more complex commands and would prefer to use shell=False and passing a list of arguments.

So what works is this form (this is a simplified example, there will be multiple streams in the final version):

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.Popen('ffmpeg.exe -i Test.avi -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=1024:1024:0:0[out1]" -map [out1] out1.mp4', shell=True)
```

This script produces the expected cropped output video.

For a list of arguments, I tried:

```
FFMPEG_PATH = 'ffmpeg.exe'
aviP='Test.avi'
sp.Popen([FFMPEG_PATH,
'-i', aviP,
'-filter_complex', '[0:v]crop=1024:1024:0:0[out1]',
'-map', '[out1] out1.mp4'])
```

When I execute this second version, simply nothing happens. (no error, no output)

I suspect I am messing up something in the map command syntax?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: I get this output - it's not informative to me?!:      CalledProcessError: Command '['ffmpeg.exe', '-i', 'C:/Users/jlarsch/Desktop/x264Test.avi', '-filter_complex', '[0:v]crop=1024:1024:0:0[out1]', '-map', '[out1] out1.mp4']' returned non-zero exit status

Comment: Did you use `check_call`? Using `check_output` should give you the stderr as well.

Comment: I did use check_output... but I also found the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
FFMPEG_PATH = 'ffmpeg.exe'
aviP='Test.avi'
sp.Popen([FFMPEG_PATH,
'-i', aviP,
'-filter_complex', '[0:v]crop=1024:1024:0:0[out1]',
'-map', '[out1]', 'out1.mp4'])
```

is the correct syntax